# When can a phrase be put after the "second" verb?

Tags: learning, grammaticality

Sorry that I don't know the right words for it, but here is an example.

Apparently the sentence

> Du musst mir helfen, das zu verstehen.

is correct, but I do not understand why "das zu verstehen" comes **after** the verb *helfen* and not before. For example, I cannot say

> Du musst gehen zum Geschäft.

One must say

> Du musst zum Geschäft gehen.

So why? Can one just keep adding "verb phrases"?

Comment: "You must help me understand this". There's no fundamental difference to other languages here.

Comment: German is a bit weird in that usually if you have a 2nd verb in the sentence, assuming there isn't any "because" or "when" or other word linking 2 sentences together, the 2nd verb goes to the end of the sentence and the 1st verb is usually the 2nd word in the sentence.

Comment: [Infinitive clauses](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Form/Infinitiv.html?lang=en) can (and usually do) go after the main clause. Shorter infinitive clause can also go before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Du musst mir helfen, das zu verstehen.
>   Du musst zum Geschäft gehen.

You are looking for a construction using *helfen* as a modal verb. Such a thing exists in German:

> Du musst mir verstehen helfen.

However, this pattern is quite limited. You can add the thing to understand:

> Du musst mir die Hausaufgaben verstehen helfen.

but this already sounds incredibly awkward to German speakers' ears. Instead, we use a dependent clause with *zu + infinitiv*. It even has a name: **Infinitivsatz**.

> Du musst mir helfen, die Hausaufgaben zu verstehen.

MUCH BETTER!

Comment: Vielen Dank! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add the following observation.

Since the sentence

> Du musst mir das verstehen helfen.

gets to complex in a way, it is natural to split it into **two** simpler sentences:

> Du musst mir helfen, das zu verstehen.

You could also split

> Du musst zum Geschäft gehen.

into

> Du musst gehen, zum Geschäft.

But the sentence was already simple to begin with. So, there is less motivation to split it up and thus the latter is a non-standard form, only rarely used, to have a certain stylistic effect.

Comment: One might add that also **"Du musst mir das zu verstehen helfen"** would count for a valid sentence, although again it is too twisted for using it in everyday language.